# How to access Spark Web UI?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running a Spark application locally of 4 nodes.  when I'm running my Application it displays my driver having this address 10.0.2.15:

```
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4040
```

at the end of running it displays :

```
INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

I tried to access the Spark Web by:
`10.0.2.15:4040` but the page is inaccessible.
Trying with the below address also didn't helped:

```
 http://localhost:18080
```

Using `ping 10.0.2.15` the result is:

```
Send a request 'Ping' 10.0.2.15 with 32 bytes of data

Waiting time exceeded

Waiting time exceeded

Waiting time exceeded

Waiting time exceeded

Ping statistics for 10.0.2.15: Packages: sent = 4, received = 0, lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

Checked the availability of the port 4040 using `netstat -a` to verify which ports are available. The result is as follow:

```
   Active connexion:

    Active       local address        Remote address                      state

    TCP          127.0.0.1:4040      DESKTOP-FF4U.....:0                 Listening
```

PS.: Knowning that my code is running succesfully. 
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4040
```

That's how Spark reports that the web UI (which is known as `SparkUI` internally) is bound to the port `4040`.

As long as the Spark application is up and running, you can access the web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040.

```
INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
...
INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

This is when a Spark application has finished (it does not really matter whether it finished properly or not). From now on, the web UI (at http://10.0.2.15:4040) is no longer available.

> I tried to access the Spark Web by: 10.0.2.15:4040 but the page is inaccessible.

That's the expected behaviour of a Spark application. Once it's completed, `4040` (which is the default port of a web UI) is no longer available.

> Trying with the below address also didn't helped: http://localhost:18080

`18080` is the default port of Spark History Server. It is a separate process and may or may not be available regardless of availability of running Spark applications.

Spark History Server is completely different from a Spark application. Quoting the [official Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact):

> It is still possible to construct the UI of an application through Spark’s history server, provided that the application’s event logs exist. You can start the history server by executing:
>
> ```
> ./sbin/start-history-server.sh
> ```
>
> This creates a web interface at http://:18080 by default, listing incomplete and completed applications and attempts.

As you could read, you have to start Spark History Server yourself to have `18080` available.

Moreover, you have to use `spark.eventLog.enabled` and `spark.eventLog.dir` configuration properties to be able to view the logs of Spark applications once they're completed their execution. Quoting the [Spark official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact):

> The spark jobs themselves must be configured to log events, and to log them to the same shared, writable directory. For example, if the server was configured with a log directory of `hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs`, then the client-side options would be:
>
> ```
> spark.eventLog.enabled true
> spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The web ui is only accessible while the Spark application is running. Once the Spark application has finished so has the UI.

To review the logs of already finished and currently running Spark applications you have to use the [Spark History server](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact).

Comment: Thank you, I checked http://localhost:18080 on the same time when my application is running, but the page is inaccessible. Can I change the configuration in the tow files: spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf ?

Comment: @sirine yes you can adjust the config in spark-defaults.conf .
Also in case I misunderstood you just now just to make this clear:You need to start the history server separately as explained under the link.

Comment: I checked the server-history-server.sh,                                    sbin="`dirname "$0"`"
sbin="`cd "$sbin"; pwd`"

. "$sbin/spark-config.sh"
. "$SPARK_PREFIX/bin/load-spark-env.sh"

if [ $# != 0 ]; then
  echo "Using command line arguments for setting the log directory is deprecated. Please "
  echo "set the spark.history.fs.logDirectory configuration option instead."
  export SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=$1"
fi

exec "$sbin"/spark-daemon.sh start org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer 1
Can I modify it ? Thank you.

Comment: @sirine not sure I understand the question. Yes you can modify this script, but I wouldn't necessarily recommend it (at the very least you will have to repeat the edit when upgrading versions for example). What do you want to achieve by editing it, that you cannot otherwise achieve?

Comment: How I can start the history server, because I checked the file, I modify the script ?

Comment: @sirine sorry it seems I'm missing something here, maybe it's due to the missing formatting in the comments. The script is not working for you ?

Comment: yes is working the script, but why I can't to access on the spark UI to see where is my application is ranning and how much clusters. I tried by http://10.0.2.15:4040 also I changed the port on 4041 and 4042 but in vein.

Comment: @sirine try `EXPORT SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS="localhost" ./server-history-server.sh`, seems it's binding to an inaccessible network interface.

Comment: I should add EXPORT SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS="localhost" ./server-history-server.sh in the script of the file start-history-server ?

Comment: @sirine nah just run it in the shell in one line like I pasted it, so that the env variable is set.

Answer (score 1):

So if you are running your spark code on a scala IDE you need to enter the below line.

scala.io.StdIn.readLine()

Later go to the web and type localhost:4040 or localhost:4041.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Before closing SparkContext, put

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
scanner.nextLine();
```

and then close the SparkContext, as

```
sparkContext.close();
```

And then access the spark UI at http://localhost:4040