# Apache Spark installation error.

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am able to install Apache spark with the given set of commands on **ubuntu 16**:

```
dpkg -i scala-2.12.1.deb 
mkdir /opt/spark 
tar -xvf spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz 
cp -rv spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/* /opt/spark 
cd /opt/spark
```

executing spark shell worked  well

```
./bin/spark-shell --master local[2]
```

return this output on the shell:

```
jai@jaiPC:/opt/spark$ ./bin/spark-shell --master local[2]
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/05/15 19:00:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/05/15 19:00:55 WARN Utils: Your hostname, jaiPC resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 172.16.16.46 instead (on interface enp4s0)
18/05/15 19:00:55 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
18/05/15 19:00:55 WARN SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some configuration may not take effect.
Spark context Web UI available at http://172.16.16.46:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[2], app id = local-1526391055793).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.2
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

but when I tried to access

```
Spark context Web UI available at http://172.16.16.46:4040
```

it shows

```
The page cannot be displayed
```

How can I resolve this problem

**Please help:**

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Where are you running Spark? If you're running locally, can you access the UI at localhost:4040 ?

Comment: Did you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322755/how-to-access-spark-web-ui

Comment: @Metropolis I have installed it locally but not able to access.